# How do I run an HTML file on VSCode using WSL? I keep getting a "chrome error"

Tags: javascript, web, windows-subsystem-for-linux, liveserver

I use WSL on my laptop to code in C and Java and that works well, but for some reason it won't run an HTML file. My PC has both linux and Windows and so I was working on a project there(HTML, CSS and JS) and want to now run it on WSL on my laptop. The code runs well in Linux so I don't get why I keep getting this error for WSL. Here is the error:
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"

I have bitdefender installed on my laptop so I thought it could be that but I  turned off the antivirus and firewall and nothing changed. I also tried getting the live server extension but that didn't work either. I have updated my windows(Windows 11 home). When I run it with just chrome it says ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and if I run it with the live server it says that it refused to connected. I tried just running an HTML file on its own and it also didn't work. I'm not really sure what else I could try.
For info I am using WSL: Ubuntu-20.04,node v20.10.0 and vscode 1.85.1.

Comment: HTML files don't "run". You need to serve the directory containing it via HTTP to connect to it with a browser. E.g. [npm-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)